# Are there any other requirements other than 'Unique ID' for getElementById('ID') to work?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I don't know why, but this code is not working! There is no error in the code other than that! Because when I change the values of num1, num2, num3 to some predefined values it works perfectly fine. Please help.

The HTML is..

```
    <h3>Choose Image</h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Ball_1</h4></td>
            <td><img src="images/b.png"></td>
            <td>No. of Images: <input type="text" id="one_number_id" value="0"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Ball_2</h4></td>
            <td><img src="images/b2.png"></td>
            <td>No. of Images: <input type="text" id="two_number_id" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Ball_3</h4></td>
            <td><img src="images/b3.png"></td>
            <td>No. of Images: <input type="text" id="three_number_id" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And this is inside Script.js

```
var one_n_img = document.getElementById("one_number_id");   
var two_n_img = document.getElementById("two_number_id");
var three_n_img = document.getElementById("three_number_id");
var num1 = one_n_img.value;
var num2 = two_n_img.value;
var num3 = three_n_img.value;
```

Comment: You probably run script before DOM created. Try to run it on window load or just put script after table in html page. Also this is good technique to self-close tags.

Comment: Looks like all works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yuU9/)

Comment: there is no problem with your code.

Comment: Thank you all, the problem is solved. Actually I was adding these number later on without using parseInt(), so...I think you got it!

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement other than a unique ID is that the element is rendered and available in the DOM. If you're script is included prior to this, then `getElementById()` will return null.

Wrap the code in the `window.onload` event, to ensure that the elements are ready for use:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var one_n_img = document.getElementById("one_number_id");   
    var two_n_img = document.getElementById("two_number_id");
    var three_n_img = document.getElementById("three_number_id");
    var num1 = one_n_img.value;
    var num2 = two_n_img.value;
    var num3 = three_n_img.value;  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need need to check inside your `Script.js`. You must run all of your script onload event. For jquery, use $(document).ready otherwise use following solution. [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)